Поиск наиболее оптимального способа заполнения QList<Object*> блоками разной длины для приближения к заданному количеству
Имеется QList<Container *>
Класс Container в свою очередь имеет QList<Item *> в котором может быть произвольное количество Item не менее одного.
Имеется QList<Item *> resList для хранения результата.
При вводе пользователем числа необходимо копировать указатели Item * из контейнеров соблюдая следующие условия:

Добавлять можно только все Item из Container
Итоговое количество Item в resList должно быть как можно ближе к числу, введенному пользователем, но не меньше.
Можно удалять ранее добавленные Item из resList, но удалять можно только все Item которые входят в общий Container
Если число, которое ввел пользователь меньше, чем количество Item в resList, то можно и удалять и добавлять по тем же правилам с тем же условием.

Задача найти наиболее оптимальный алгоритм, чтобы как можно меньше перебирать списки и как можно меньше удалять и добавлять Item в/из resList
upd:
Попробую более детально расписать суть задачи (на абстрактном примере), так как на основе предоставленных ранее данных, вероятно, сложно дать точный ответ.
Имеется некий склад предметов одного типа. Предметы могут храниться в контейнерах разного размера от 1 до N, либо лежать без контейнера поштучно.
На склад приходит запрос выдать x количество предметов. Склад на основе имеющихся в наличии предметов должен постараться выдать точно x либо больше, но не меньше. При этом в приоритете выдавать сначала предметы контейнерами и только потом, если подходящего контейнера нет выдавать поштучно. При этом если от того же пользователя приходит повторный запрос на новое количество y, склад должен проанализировать:

Сколько ранее выдано предметов и какой конфигурацией комплектов/россыпью
Сколько осталось в наличии и в какой конфигурации
На основе этих данных либо выдать еще, если запрошено больше, либо забрать часть, если запрошено меньше, либо забрать часть и выдать что-то в другой конфигурации, чтобы соблюсти условие выдать точно y либо больше, совершив как можно меньше действий возврата-выдачи.

Примеры:
Допустим имеем контейнеры с количеством предметов [4,4,3,2] и еще 1 россыпью.
Пользователь запросил 6, значит нужно выдать первый и четвертый комплект.
Затем пользователь запросил вместо 6 7. Значит нужно четвертый забрать, а взамен выдать третий.
Затем пользователь запросил 9, значит выдать еще четвертый
Надеюсь теперь я более детально описал суть задачи.

Похоже на задачу о наборе суммы (subset sum), может решаться динамическим программированием, темы такие на SO есть. Часть про удаление можно только все Item которые входят в общий Container сомнительная - зачем тогда добавлять целый контейнер, если его потом весь удалять? Стоит показать несложные примеры для уточнения.

Представим магазин с яйцами. Они хранятся в лотках разного размера от 1 до N. Приходит Маша и просит 16 яиц. Продавец собирает ей наиболее подходящие лотки. Если имеющимися лотками никак нельзя набрать ровно 16 - продавец набирает ближайшее большее количество. Приходит Петя и все повторяется. Затем возвращается Маша и просит продавца вместо 16, например 20. Яйца подписаны номером лотков. Продавец должен принять решение дать еще 4, если есть такой лоток, забрать какие-то ранее выданные и выдать новые, чтобы как можно точнее выдать 20. Выдавать и забирать строго лотками - условие задачи.

@MBo Спасибо за наводку. В целом да, речь об этом. Но просто набрать с нуля не трудно. У меня ступор случился как раз когда нужно добавить или убавить количество при этом совершив минимум действий (не просто все забрать и выдать заново)

Задача при умеренных значениях сумм решается динамическим программированием.
Вначале заводим массив А длиной в нужную сумму +1, заполняем большим числом X, A[0]=0.
Затем для каждого значения контейнера v проходим по массиву сверху вниз. A[i]= min(A[i-v]+1, A[i]) - это означает, что сумму i можно составить из v и i-v, выбрав минимальное количество слагаемых из текущего и новой суммы.
После работы алгоритма ячейка массива A[neededsum] содержит количество (минимальное) контейнеров для набора  данной суммы. Для учёта перебора массив нужно удлинить и проверять ячейки от neededsum вверх.
Похожим образом работаем при обновлении нужной суммы, только теперь отложенные ранее контейнеры используем со знаком минус, а в качестве целевой суммы берём разность между прошлой и новой. При этом суммы могут быть отрицательными, индексы массива неудобны, можно взять словарь.
Если алгоритм заработает, останется небольшая модификация - сохранять при выборе минимума информацию о том, какие именно контейнеры использованы на данную сумму.
